# Как записать данные в переменную из базы данных

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

я плохо понимаю в сиквеле и у меня созрел вопрос.
Я пишу бота для ВК на php.
У меня есть база данных с айди вк и доступом администратора.
Мне нужно это как-то вытянуть из БД и записать в переменную,а затем вывести или сравнить методом in_array.

Если честно - я совсем камушек и в этом не разбираюсь. В интернете искал - не нашел =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил сам.
Производим поиск

```
$peer_id = 2000000003
$findbase = R::Findone('settings','peer_id = ?',[$peer_id]);
$find = $findbase->kickall;
```

Теперь у нас в этих переменных есть значения.

Answer (score 1):

Вы даёте слишком мало данных. Опишите структуру вашей БД, используется ли какой-то php-фреймворк и/или Doctrine или вы хотите залезть в БД просто с помощью php. Никто не сомжет вам помочь, если вы полностью не раскроете суть вопроса и не опишите то что есть на данный момент.

Comment: Ок,раскрываю суть. Я использую red bean php - для меня удобная штучка. Юзаю я обычную базу данных mysql na phpmyadmin.
https://imgur.com/BuCeTtW

Нужно взять айди отправителя сообщения и сравнить его айди в базе данных с его доступом. То бишь,если у айди 123456789 доступ = 1 - отказано в доступе. Если у него доступ в таблице - 2 - команда выполнена

Comment: приложите структуру таблицы из которой хотите сделать выборку и связанных таблиц (если есть внешние связи).